# Using Django Rest Framework > 2.4 to get children of parent with @detail_route

Tags: json, django, rest, django-views, django-rest-framework

I had this working great less than DRF 2.4, but the change to 2.4+ uses @detail_route.

When I do a GET to `/api/parent/7/children` I expect to get all the children that belong to Parent 7.

But I'm getting an empty array.

Here's my code:

```
class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
    model = models.Parent

    @detail_route()
    def children(self, request, pk):
        parent = self.get_object()
        children = parent.children.all()
        serializer = ChildrenSerializer(children)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return models.Parent.objects.all()
        else:
            return models.Parent.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.user = self.request.user
```

When I go to the endpoint `/api/parent/7/children` in the API viewer the response I get is:

```
{
    "detail": "Not found"
}
```

Any suggestions?

I like this better in principle, you can be much more declarative about what is happening. I know I can set methods on `children` so I don't have to do a @link and @action for the same resource. Just need to get past this hurdle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is your issue or not, but you have a typo in the example as presented...

```
children = parent.children.all()
serializer = ChildrenSerializer(Children)
```

Should be:

```
children = parent.children.all()
serializer = ChildrenSerializer(children)
```

You're passing the `Children` class to be serialized, not the children instance.

Comment: I wish that was the issue. I fixed the typo. Thanks Tom. Other than that, does it look right?

Comment: Looks right to me. (Tho also note that `get_object` shouldn't take any arguments, at least in the latest versions.) I'd do some debugging in your `children` method - Is it being called? What is `.get_object()` returning? Are there any items in the `children` queryset, etc...

Comment: the response I'm getting is: { "detail": "Not found" } . I'll edit the above to get the pk out of the get_object().

Comment: To clarify, if I DON'T include the PK in the get_object I get an error about `  

'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'`